# Configure Webpack to handle cache-busting

Tags: javascript, configuration

I'm not very familiar with webpack, and I was very afraid that what I implemented for cache busting would break something. What I have seems to work. When I open up the built folder, under `pub`, I see 3 files:

- main.someHashHere.js
- index.html
- manifest.someOtherHashHere.js

Previously, before I implemented cache-busting, there was no index.html. (1) I'm wondering, is it supposed to show up in this folder with the other two js files? (In previous deployments, before adding cache-busting, it there was no index.html file there).

Here's what I have:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var AssetsPlugin = require('assets-webpack-plugin'); // *
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin'); // *
var WebpackMd5Hash = require('webpack-md5-hash'); // *


var basePlugins = [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    __PRODUCTION__: true,
    'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),
  }),
];

var usedPlugins = [
  new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    compressor: {
      warnings: false,
    },
  }),
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ // *
    names: "manifest" // *
  }), // *
  new AssetsPlugin(), // *
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin(), // *
  new WebpackMd5Hash(), // *
];


/* Config */
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: [path.join(__dirname, '/lib/main')],
  },
  eslint: {
    configFile: 'lib/.eslintrc',
  },
  resolve: {
    root: path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib'),
    alias: {
      ...
    },
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/pub/'),
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js', // *
    chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].js', // *
    sourceMapFilename: '[name].js.map',
    publicPath: '/pub/',
  },
  plugins: usedPlugins,
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      ...
    ],
    loaders: [
      ...
    ],
  },
};
```

Everything commented with an asterik was included for the sole purpose of cache-busting.

(2) What I'm most concerned about is whether or not I have added anything that will be breaking or have any unintended consequences?

Comment: Is this your code or some else's?

Comment: Is there anything that indicates otherwise @TolaniJaiye-Tikolo ?

Comment: @denis I just assumed based on the OP's question why they are three files under the Pub Folder. Correct me if I'm wrong about this

Comment: Some files are auto-generated OP might be wondering about that, it looks fine to me.